Why while running "sudo apt install python3-xyz" it crashes?
My problem is that I wanna install pyinstaller and pygame extensions for my python3 program. So, when I was running the command that the python3 console told me to execute ( The command was apt install python3) it crashed and it told me told me the next reference error:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Then I ran sudo apt install python3-xyz but sudo request didn't work properly and it returned me the next reference error:
E: Unable to locate package python3-xyz

For giving more information, my laptop is a Lenovo Legion and my ubuntu version is the 24.03
Thanks

There is no package named python3-xyz in the Ubuntu repositories, which is why it cannot be located. It's unclear where you found such instructions, but let them know their instructions are inaccurate.

Permission denied  you forgot sudo.

Please [edit] your question and give us the full context. There is no way that the python3 console told you to run apt install python3. That command installs pytyhon3, but clearly you had python3 already if you were running it. Also, it's an integral part of Ubuntu, you wouldn't be able to run Ubuntu without it. So please clarify exactly what you are doing and show the exact commands you ran and messages you received.

Python 3 is included in all currently supported of Ubuntu, so it is already installed for sure. No need to run sudo apt install python3.

Note that changing the default python version of an Ubuntu Desktop system will likely break it.  Don't force install other versions.  However, it is possible to install other versions in alternate locations.  It's not clear from your question if this is necessary.

It doesn't look like anything "crashed", whatever that means.
